# Refresh collectionView on viewdidload after retrieving UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, collections, view

I have a collection view, and you can select the items in it and toggle them on and off by changing the background colour.  The cells are toggled on/off thanks to a boolean I have in an arrow I made for all of the cells.  I have saved the bool value but when I try to write them back into the array and use `collectionView.reloadData()`the app crashes.  My  `collectionView`code is:

```
extension OLLViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {  //set the amount of items in the CollectionView to the amount of items in the OLLData dictionary
    return OLLData.OLLCasesList.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {  //set each cell to a different mamber of the dict.
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OLLCell", for: indexPath) as! OLLCell
    cell.imageView.backgroundColor = OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected ? UIColor.orange : UIColor.clear //change colour if selected

    let image = OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._imageName

    cell.label.text = image
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)

    let savedIsSelected = defaults.bool(forKey: Key.isSelected)

    OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected = savedIsSelected
    //collectionView.reloadData() //when uncommented it crashes the app

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)  { //detect if case selected and reload CollectionView
    let caseName = OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._imageName
    print(caseName, OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected)
    OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected = !OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected
    defaults.set(OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected, forKey: Key.isSelected)
    collectionView.reloadItems(at:[indexPath])

    collectionView.reloadData()

    if OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected == true { //if the item is selected, add to selectedCases array
        selectedCases.append(OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._id)
        selectedCaseNames.append(OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._imageName)
        print(selectedCases, selectedCaseNames) //debugging
        numberOfSelectedCases.text = String(selectedCases.count)
    }
    else if OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected == false { //remove from selectedCases array
        selectedCases.removeAll(where: { $0 == OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._id })
        selectedCaseNames.removeAll(where: { $0 == OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._imageName })
        print(selectedCases, selectedCaseNames) //debugging
        numberOfSelectedCases.text = String(selectedCases.count)
    }
}
```

`._isSelected`is the boolean that says whether the cell is 'toggled'.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d79f410)`  Never seen this kind of error before.

Comment: Never call `reloadData` from `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Ah ok - but do you know how I can refresh the selected Items?

Comment: When you call `reloadData` from `cellForRowAt` , you're creating an infinite loop. `cellForRowAt` happens when the collection view is reloading, so if you call it inside, you can see how the calls would never end.

Comment: Ah right that makes sense

Comment: You shouldn't try and coordinate two arrays - You should have a single array of a suitable struct with properties.  You should only need to store the id.  Your use of  user defaults doesn't make sense either; You only have a single key, so you have no way of identifying which case the `selected` state applies to.  You also don't typically use _ to prefix properties in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, uncommenting that line will produce an infinite loop. `cellForRowAt` happens because the collection view is reloading, so calling a refresh while the collection view is refreshing is no good.

So your issue is that you don't know how to display selected cells in your collection view, right?

Here's a function that fires right before the collection view is about to display a cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                    willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
                    forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    <#code#>
}
```

Inside this function, you should:

1. Cast `cell` into your `OLLCell` (safely if you want to be thorough)
2. Look at your data and see if the cell should be selected `OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected`
3. Ask your casted cell to change its colors/UI/appearance according to your `._isSelected` boolean

Step 3 has a *VERY* important caveat. You should be changing the UI when `._isSelected` is false AND when it's true. Because the collection view reuses cells, old UI state will randomly recur. So setting it every time is a good way to ensure the behavior you want.

Here's an example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                    willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
                    forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    //Cast the vanilla cell into your custom cell so you have access 
    //to OLLCell's specific functions and properties.
    //Also make sure the indexPath falls in the indices of your data 
    if let myCastedCell = cell as? OLLCell,
       0 ..< OLLData.OLLCasesList.count ~= indexPath.item 
    {
        myCastedCell.imageView.backgroundColor = OLLData
            .OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected 
                ? UIColor.orange 
                : UIColor.clear 
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this go against what I've done with didSelectItemAt?  And also, what do you mean by cast?  I'm fairly new with swift and am not familiar with the terminology...

Comment: You wrote this line `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OLLCell", for: indexPath) as! OLLCell` in your `cellForItemAt` function. What's happening is that you're asking your collection view to reuse one of its cells with the "OLLCell" ID. Just asking your collection view for `dequeueReusableCell` will return a UICollectionViewCell. when you do `as! OLLCell` you are forcing UICollectionViewCell into being OLLCell, or rather, you are force casting it.

Comment: In my answer, I am doing `cell as? OLLCell`. Instead of your `as!`, I'm typing `as?`. This is a safe cast and is useful when you have lots of _different_ kinds of cells. It's basically asking "Hey Mr. UICollectionView, is this UICollectionViewCell here an OLLCell?" If it says "yeah" then you can access the OLLCell's imageView.

Comment: And no, I don't think it goes against your `didSelectItemAt` function. You're not changing any UI in there, you're just changing backing data state. In my `willDisplayCell` function, I'm just reading your backing data state and toggling the UI color based on what it says.

Comment: No problem, upvote my answer if I was helpful, please. If this doesn't solve your issue, let me know.

Comment: Sure - also what do you mean by "make sure the indexPath falls in the indices of your data"? Is that `OLLData.OLLCasesList[indexPath.item]._isSelected`?

Comment: Unless you've got rock solid state handling, the state of your data could possibly change while the collection view is doing its business. For example, let's say your data has 100 elements in it, and then some outside async operation deletes half of it. Suddenly, indices 49 through 99 don't exist. If your collection view tries to access `OLLData.OLLCasesList[74]`, your program is going to crash because it's out of bounds. This line `0 ..< OLLData.OLLCasesList.count ~= indexPath.item` makes sure `74` is in range 0 up to 50. It's good to be safe

Comment: I've used the code that you wrote in your answer, but it doesn't highlight the saved toggled cells on startup - is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in there. Is all of the code in there getting called? If the contents of the if statement aren't being executed, check why the if statement is failing. Is it because the casting is no good? Is it because the function is trying to access data that's out of bounds? Are the ._isSelected values in your data what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes it is being called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192193/discussion-between-xavier-l-and-yachtsamba).